# Java Mail Как послать информацию из контакт формы на мой gmail?

Tags: java, java-ee, smtp, javamail

Пишу учебный проект.

В процессе создания Contact-Form.

Нужно после субмита отослать на мой имейл информацию,которая была заполнена в форме. При поиске в сети как это сделать наткнулся на tutorials,

например как этот [туториал по java mail API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gy2eEZhLihk). В туториале не упоминается о том что нужно установить SMTP Web Server.

В сети прочитал что для того чтобы посылать имейлы надо установить такой веб сервер..

Так и не понял что надо для того чтобы отослать на данном этапе сообшение с Contact Form.. Кто может хелп плиз..

Comment: «В сети прочитал что для того чтобы посылать имейлы надо установить такой веб сервер.» – это где Вы такое прочитали?

Comment: [Вот пример](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) как отправлять email.